# How do I write a script to identify and manipulate a specific drive in the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I'm trying to write a short script that can automatically unmount and remount a partition, without knowing where the drive is currently mounted.

The following command sort of works for me:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdX /mnt/rec
```

The issue is, I'm running Linux live, and can't install it on my hard drive. As such, whenever I reboot the computer, /dev/sdX will sometimes mount as /dev/sdb, or /dev/sdd. As such, I can't just run a script to automatically mount the drive where I need to, without using

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In order to verify what the drives are currently mounted as.

My question is: Is there a way to identify a drive, that's agnostic to where it's currently mounted?

Comment: What does it mean to identify the drive independent of where it is mounted?  What's on the drive to tell you it is the one you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

This was an annoying issue up until 2005 or so, but now can access devices based on device-independent identifiers thanks to `udev`.

Check out  `/dev/disk/` for all the various ways in which your partitions are automatically categorized independently of their `/dev/sd*` name:

```
$ find /dev/disk/
/dev/disk/by-uuid
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d7a395e4-e6fd-49bc-bbd9-af9c6a43211d
/dev/disk/by-partuuid
/dev/disk/by-partuuid/4434a42f-01
/dev/disk/by-path
/dev/disk/by-path/acpi-VMBUS:01-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
/dev/disk/by-path/acpi-VMBUS:01-scsi-0:0:0:0
/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:07.1-ata-2
/dev/disk/by-id
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600224805c60e27d40a2d50b3961022c-part1
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600224805c60e27d40a2d50b3961022c-part1
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600224805c60e27d40a2d50b3961022c
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600224805c60e27d40a2d50b3961022c
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Virtual_CD
```

These are all completely transparent symlinks to their backing device, so you can easily see what they correspond to:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/d7a395e4-e6fd-49bc-bbd9-af9c6a43211d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 28 10:38 /dev/disk/by-uuid/d7a395[..]  -> ../../sda1
```

The `by-uuid` entries are generally your best bet, but `partuuid` and `label` may also be useful for less Linux-y file systems.

Comment: Thank you! This works. 

I'd like to add, where you would use the statement: `/dev/sdX`

You can replace it with: 

`UUID="000000000000000"`

Where the zeros is your device UUID.